# ssis message box (job runs a package)

Tags: ssis, jobs, message

In my SSIS package there is a Script which has message box pops up for each item in foreach loop. This is good for me when debugging. But what happens when I run this package using Job? I know I want see any message boxes but does it stay somewhere in memory? Does it have any influence?

Answer (score 1):

Try using either the event log or a database audit table to record the activity.  You will not have a handle over any message box for a deployed package and you do not want a self contained scheduled package to require human intervention to keep it processing.